# Typing Issue in Recursive Functions in a Contextual Type Inference System

Tags: haskell, recursion, error-handling, type-inference

I have a function that helps me determine the type of a variable based on the context. We define it as follows: How we define the `ctx:`, `type Ctx = [(String, Type)]`, the signature of the function `vt: vt :: Ctx -> Expr -> Type`. The case for variables is:

```hs
-- Cases for variables
vt ctx (Var x) = case lookup x ctx of
                    Just t -> t
                    Nothing -> error ("Variable not found" ++ show x ++ show ctx)
```

And for `let`:

```hs
-- Cases for let
vt ctx (Let var e1 e2) = vt ((var, vt ctx e1) : ctx) e2
```

However, I encounter an issue when testing it with recursive functions. In `e1`, we come across the variable from which we want to determine the type, and this generates an error. How could I solve this?

What we tried to do was, knowing that in our function's test the type variable must be of integer type, we looked for free variables, but we couldn't get it to identify it as what it is. Therefore, we directly specified that it was of type int, but we believe that it is not practical.

Comment: Require type annotations on all binders or do type inference. If you choose the latter, bidirectional typing is a particularly simple implementation strategy; Hindley-Milner is more complicated but requires fewer annotations.

Comment: You are thinking a lot about how to *implement* it, but you don't seem to be clear about what the answer should even be.  Here's a recursive function: `f x = f x + 1` -- what should the types be (and how do you know)?